# Fractional Interpolator Block is not found in gnuradio 3.10

Tags: gnuradio

I'm trying to following the sample to learn sdr in
[HackRF WBFM发射](http://www.hackrf.net/2014/01/wbfm%E5%8F%91%E5%B0%84/)

It uses a "Factional Interpolator" block, but this block is not found in gnuradio version 3.10.

How can we do to replace "Factional Interpolator" block with other blocks?

Answer (score -1):

That article is **really** obsolete, as it depends on GNU Radio 3.7. I'd strongly recommend you follow https://tutorials.gnuradio.org instead, which is kept updated by the same people that develop GNU Radio!

Anyway, that block has been called "Fractional Resampler" for multiple versions, if I remember correctly.